# GCP: How can I protect my vm Instance from internet access, but keeping it accessible from API Gateway

Tags: google-cloud-platform, api-gateway

I have a vm instance that makes our service in Go, and we want our users to go through an API Gateway before acessign the vm Instance (for monitoring, authentification and other reasons...).

We have bought registered `private-acme.com` DNS with Google, and the Go service is accessible with this URL : `http://private-acme.com:1234/service`
The API Gateway has an Open API yaml that redirect to this service, and everything works correctly. The API url is given by the console: `https://acme-api-abcdefg123.ew.gateway.dev`

So `https://acme-api-abcdefg123.ew.gateway.dev/service` redirects to `http://private-acme.com:1234/service` and everything works. But `http://private-acme.com:1234/service` remains accessible and don't require the API key we have setup on the Gateway

So I wanted to setup a firewall rule on the vm Instance. For the moment, I have a firewall rule named `gw-apps` with a `gw` tag, that allows `0.0.0.0/0` range and port `1234`.

Unfortunately it seems to me impossible to create a firewall rule that would allow the vm instance to be accessed only by the Api gateway IP. It’s not possible to assign an IP nor an IP range to the API gateway.

The gateway IP is currently `216.239.XXX.YYY`, but if I put `216.0.0.0/8` in the firewall instead of `0.0.0.0/0`, it fails. Anyway we are not  sure the address will start by `216`

It’s not neither possible to tag the API Gateway with `gw` , I don’t know why. It would have allow to create a source filter for the firewall

It is recommended to do what we want with a connector (50$/month...) but it’s only applicable to CloudRun, Cloud Function or App Engine, not API Gateway

Any idea on how to protect my vm Instance ?

Comment: My suggestion is to look into enabling Identity-Aware Proxy on Compute Engine and then configuring backend authorization for API Gateway. That is how it is done for API Gateway calling Cloud Run, Functions, etc. These links will help: https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/securing-backend-services and https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/concepts-overview